# Windows phone 8 Viewport in update 3 includes system tray

Tags: html, cordova, windows-phone-8, viewport

I have an app for Windows Pone 8 with PhoneGap and designed in HTML5, it has a fixed footer in it and system tray visible. 
At first when the phone (Lumia 820) had Windows Phone 8 with Update 1 the footer would show normally. I recently updated phone to Windows Phone 8 update 3 which has some changes in IE, the fixed footer is displaced few pixel below and now it looks cut off. If I hide the system tray for the page as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518145/windows-phone-8-html5-viewport-is-higher-than-the-screen-after-update-to-8-0-103) the footer works normally.

But now here the system tray is not accessible, how can I achieve that viewport works normally but I also see system tray?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5440) there is a [cordova-plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar) to handle the statusbar correctly.