# Cordova WP8 App Viewport Scaling incorrect

Tags: html, cordova, windows-phone-8, kendo-ui

I have an app that has been built to support Blackberry, Android and now Windows Phone 8.

I am using the kendo-ui html5 and cordova frameworks. The applications builds and runs perfectly on Android and BB however the views and elements are all out within the the wp8 application. (Fonts too small - fixed pixel heights incorrect) - Assumed to be the scaling or viewport size.

I have added the following into the head, and also insured that it is set after the application init (within Kendoui).

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />
```

However the scaling and sizes is all wrong on my HTC 8X device and emulators. This must be a common issue for HTML5 applications ported from other platforms.

Any advice or items missing to enable this to work with windows phone 8?

Comment: I have the same problem but with other framework, did you find the solution?

Comment: I used dp rather than px and it sorted itself out.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin to fix wp8 viewport https://github.com/lisovin/cordova-wp8-viewport

Also look at the first answer of this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476010/phonegap-windows-phone-8-viewport-meta-scaling-issue) This might help you.

Here is another suggestion

In MainPage.xaml change

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
```

to

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518145/windows-phone-8-html5-viewport-is-higher-than-the-screen-after-update-to-8-0-103)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this plugin and my application wouldn't run. WP8.1. I also already have the system tray set to false. I found a few blogs but nothing seemed to work. I think it's a kendoui issue.